# Unstack row label (pivot table)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-3.7

I would like to unstack row label names using Python and already cleaned the data to remove "grand total" and "na" rows.

The code :

```
Description   | Table    |  Chair
***Manila***  |          |   
Apple         |     1    |    3
Pair          |     0    |    1
Orange        |     1    |    0
Watermelon    |     0    |    5
Banana        |     0    |    7
***Quezon***  |          |  
DragonFruit   |     0    |    0
StarApple     |     0    |    0
Longan        |     0    |    1
Cherries      |     1    |    2
Mango         |     0    |    5
```

Table image :

[image: how raw data looks like]

[image]

How I would like the code to look like:

```
Description  |   Day   |    Table  |  Chair
Manila    |    1     |     1    |   3
Manila    |    2     |     0    |   1
Manila    |    3     |     1    |   0
Manila    |    4     |     0    |   5
Manila    |    5     |     0    |   7
Quezon    |    1     |     0    |   0
Quezon    |    2     |     0    |   0
Quezon    |    3     |     0    |   1
Quezon    |    4     |     1    |   2
Quezon    |    5     |     0    |   5
```

Table image :

[image]

Comment: Welcome MarthaF! I can't be sure from the example data you've provided, but try `df = df.reset_index()`. Explanation: when a pandas index has consecutive duplicate labels, pandas hides all duplicate labels, showing only the first one. The labels are still there for each row, and one way to force them to show is to reset the index, which by default inserts it as the leftmost column. Of course, this modifies the DataFrame, which might be fine if you don't need to use indexing operations.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I've already tried running the code df.reset_index() which returned the same value except for the column index (which was from another documentation). Not sure how the code worked. The output for the row labels/headers are still Manila NaN NaN NaN. Tried a for loop while inserting a new column based on Day being NaN resulted in a 12 * 12 table.

Comment: It might help to know how you created the dataframe.

Comment: @busybear data frame was create using df = pd.read_excel(file_path, nrows=100, skiprows= 10, header=1) . header [0,1] does not work as the original file has multiple NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['Manila',1,2,3,4,5,'Quezon',1,2,3,4,5],
                  'Table':['',1,0,1,0,0,'',0,0,0,1,0],
                  'Chair':['',3,1,0,5,7,'',0,0,1,2,5]})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Description Table Chair
0       Manila            
1            1     1     3
2            2     0     1
3            3     1     0
4            4     0     5
5            5     0     7
6       Quezon            
7            1     0     0
8            2     0     0
9            3     0     1
10           4     1     2
11           5     0     5
```

Create a new column from words only using regex and fill forward:

```
df['Group'] = df['Description'].str.extract('(\w+)').ffill()

#Drop those "header records"  
df_out = df[df['Description'].str.contains('\w+').isna()]\
           .reindex(['Group','Description','Table','Chair'], axis=1)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
     Group Description Table Chair
1   Manila           1     1     3
2   Manila           2     0     1
3   Manila           3     1     0
4   Manila           4     0     5
5   Manila           5     0     7
7   Quezon           1     0     0
8   Quezon           2     0     0
9   Quezon           3     0     1
10  Quezon           4     1     2
11  Quezon           5     0     5
```

---

```
#Another way, look for blanks in table or chairs:

 df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['Manila',1,2,3,4,5,'Quezon',1,2,3,4,5],
                  'Table':[np.nan,1,0,1,0,0,np.nan,0,0,0,1,0],
                  'Chair':[np.nan,3,1,0,5,7,np.nan,0,0,1,2,5]})


m = df['Table'].isna()

df['Group'] = df.loc[m, 'Description']

df['Group'] = df['Group'].ffill()

df_out = df.loc[~m].reindex(['Group','Description','Table','Chair'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Group Description  Table  Chair
1   Manila           1    1.0    3.0
2   Manila           2    0.0    1.0
3   Manila           3    1.0    0.0
4   Manila           4    0.0    5.0
5   Manila           5    0.0    7.0
7   Quezon           1    0.0    0.0
8   Quezon           2    0.0    0.0
9   Quezon           3    0.0    1.0
10  Quezon           4    1.0    2.0
11  Quezon           5    0.0    5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is a pandas Dataframe just reset the index as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Gustavo, print(df) from my end returns Manila and Quezon under Description. How did a new column index print from print(df) ? Thanks.